Problem with running a python code with NLTK on Render platform
I have my django project running on Render just fine, and i've been considering on implementing a chatbot using nltk. The problem occurs the moment the project itself is about to run. For some reason, it keeps trying to access stopwords multiple times and then saying that it is already updated. It keeps going without stopping whatsoever.
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /opt/render/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/stopwords.zip.
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /opt/render/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /opt/render/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!

These are the messages that keeps repeating.
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /opt/render/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[2024-04-02 16:53:45 -0400] [59] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:60)
[2024-04-02 16:53:45 -0400] [60] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 60)
[2024-04-02 16:53:47 -0400] [59] [ERROR] Worker (pid:60) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[2024-04-02 16:53:47 -0400] [68] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 68
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /opt/render/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!

Ant this is what causes it to go in a loop again.
import nltk
import re
import os
import csv

from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
import random
from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from django.conf import settings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

nltk.download('stopwords')
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
split_ratio = 0.8
def preprocess(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
    filtered_words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
    return filtered_words

def extract_tagged(sentences):
    features = []
    for tagged_word in sentences:
        word, tag = tagged_word
        if tag=='NN' or tag=='NNS' or tag=='VBP' or tag=='RB' or tag=='VBZ' or tag=='VBG' or tag=='PRP' or tag=='JJ':
            features.append(word)
    return features

def extract_features(text):
    words = preprocess(text)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)
    extracted_features = extract_tagged(tags)
    stemmed_words = [stemmer.stem(x) for x in extracted_features]
    result = [lmtzr.lemmatize(x) for x in stemmed_words]
    return result

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

def extract_feature_from_dic(data):
    result = []
    corpus = []
    answers = {}
    for (text, category, answer) in data:
        features = extract_features(text)
        corpus.append(features)
        result.append((word_feats(features), category))
        answers[category] = answer
    return (result, sum(corpus,[]), answers)

def get_content(filename):
    doc = os.path.join(filename)
    with open(doc, 'r') as content_file:
        lines = csv.reader(content_file,delimiter='|')
        data = [x for x in lines if len(x) == 3]
        return data

def split_dataset(data, split_ratio):
    random.shuffle(data)
    data_length = len(data)
    train_split = int(data_length * split_ratio)
    return (data[:train_split]), (data[train_split:])

def train_using_decision_tree(training_data, test_data):
    classifier = nltk.classify.DecisionTreeClassifier.train(training_data, entropy_cutoff=0.6, support_cutoff=6)
    classifier_name = type(classifier).__name__
    training_set_accuracy = nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,training_data)
    print('training set accuracy: ', training_set_accuracy)
    test_set_accuracy = nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_data)
    print('test set accuracy: ', test_set_accuracy)
    return classifier, classifier_name, test_set_accuracy, training_set_accuracy

def train_using_naive_bayes(train, test):
    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train)
    classifier_name = type(classifier).__name__
    training_set_accuracy = nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier,train)
    test_set_accuracy = nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test)
    return classifier, classifier_name, test_set_accuracy, training_set_accuracy

data = get_content('chatbot/leaves.txt')

features_data, corpus, answers = extract_feature_from_dic(data)
training_data, test_data = split_dataset(features_data, split_ratio)
dtclass, classname, testacc, trainacc = train_using_decision_tree(training_data, test_data)

def reply(input_sentece):
    category = dtclass.classify(word_feats(extract_features(input_sentece)))
    return answers[category]

This is the code from the file nltk.py that is used by the views.py in my chatbot folder. After doing some trial and error, I think the error starts from the line 'tags = nltk.pos_tag(words)' inside the extract_features function. I imagine it has to do with me trying to use nltk like that but i'm not sure how to solve this.
Just in case, I'll also add on here the text file i am using:
Hey there!|Greetings|Hey there! I'm Dexcter, here to help with your leave enquiries.
Good morning!|Greetings|Good morning! Dexcter here, at your service for your leave needs.
Hey, how's it going?|Greetings|Hey, how's it going? Dexcter here, ready to assist you.
Well met!|Greetings|Well met! Dexcter here, ready to help with your leave queries.
Howdy!|Greetings|Howdy! Dexcter here, ready to help with your leave enquiries.
Hello|Greetings|Hello, I am Dexcter. I will serve your leave enquiries.
hi|Greetings|Hello, I am Dexcter. I will serve your leave enquiries.
help me|Help|How can I help you?
thank you|Closing|You are very welcome!
Farewell|Goodbye|Farewell! Feel free to reach out if you need assistance in the future.
Take care|Goodbye|Take care! If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask.
Until next time|Goodbye|Until next time! Have a wonderful day.
See you later|Goodbye|See you later! Don't hesitate to return if you have more inquiries.
Bye for now|Goodbye|Bye for now! Feel free to come back anytime.
Catch you later|Goodbye|Catch you later! Let me know if there's anything else I can assist you with.
Goodbye|Goodbye|Goodbye for now! If you need further assistance, don't hesitate to ask.
types of leaves?|Leaves-Type|Currently, I know only two leaves: optional and annual.
type leaves?|Leaves-Type|Currently, I know only two leaves: optional and annual.
leaves type?|Leaves-Type|Currently, I know only two leaves: optional and annual.
leaves type?|Leaves-Type|Currently, I know only two leaves: optional and annual.
how many annual leaves have I took?|Utilized-Annual-Leaves|You have used 2 annual leaves.
how many annual leaves did I take?|Utilized-Annual-Leaves|You have used 2 annual leaves.
annual leaves taken?|Utilized-Annual-Leaves|You have used 2 annual leaves.
how many optional leaves have I took?|Utilized-Optional-Leaves|You have used 2 optional leaves.
how many optional leaves did I take?|Utilized-Optional-Leaves|You have used 2 optional leaves.
optional leaves taken?|Utilized-Optional-Leaves|You have used 2 optional leaves.

If there's anyone who's tried on using NLTK with django and with Render, please let me know on how I can solve this.
